# Compare two different java collection objects with a common attribute using java streams api

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have two Sets containing 2 different objects

```
1. Set<A> 
2. Set<B>
```

```
    class A {
       private String id;
       private String name;
       private B objB;
    }
    
    class B {
       private String id;
       private String email;
    }
```

I want to check if any object of A in the first Set has the same "id" in the second Set B.

If it `b.getId().contains(a.getId)`, then that B object will be set in A object.

```
objA.setB(objB);
```

Based on a Predicate how can we store B object into A based on matching "id" attribute value (using Java streams)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First arrange all the `id` values from the `B` objects into a `Map` for fast access. Then loop the `A` objects, looking up each `A` object’s `id` for a match in the map.

```
Map<String,B> mapB = new HashMap<>();
for (B element : setB) {
    mapB.put(element.id, element);
}
setA.forEach (
    a ->{
        B b = mapB.get(a.getId());
        if(b!=null){
            a.setB(b);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: For even better performance you can assign `mapB.get(a.getId())` to a variable to avoid calling it twice.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through your master set using `forEach`.

```
aSet.forEach( … )
```

To assign a reference to the `objB` field, you’ll need to change the access level modifier appropriately, to something other than `private`.

For each of those `A` objects, we need to search the `bSet` for a match. Doing this search with a stream means we get an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) as a result. We need to test each Optional to see if it carries a payload. If so, assign that payload’s `B` object to our `A` object.

I am guessing at the syntax here, untested code. I will try later. Hopefully this first draft can point you in the right direction.

```
aSet.forEach (
    a ->
        bSet
        .stream()
        .filter( b -> b.id.equals( a.id ) )
        .findAny()
        .ifPresent( b -> a.objB = b )
);
```

This approach is *not* optimized for performance. For better speed, see the [Answer by ruby yang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78236886/642706).

Comment: Thanks Basil. That worked flawlessly!!!! Am afraid I have to run 5700000+ records. Not sure about the optimization.

Comment: @sairajgemini if you want a more optimized solution look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78236886